# Wireless Signal Strength + Performance

Tags: wifi

We have two access points on the shop floor. One of the AP's is not performing correctly with erratic signal strength and connectivity. Are there any open source tools available to measure performance of a wireless access point or router?

Answer (score 3):

[KisMAC](http://trac.kismac-ng.org/) or [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/),  will allow you to monitor signal strengths fluctuations and/or interference causing problems for your access point(s), possibly helping you diagnose the issue.  If you have the budget, you could invest in a [Wi-Spy](http://www.metageek.net/) card.

Answer (score 2):

[NetStumbler](http://www.stumbler.net/) is a good free tool for measuring the performance of wireless connections.

[image]

Comment: +1 NetStumbler has helped me diagnose a few networks when windows wasn't reporting any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fond of [inSIDDe](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider)r from metageek.

Comment: Netstumbler has indeed not been updated for a whole while and only has full support for ancient wireless cards. While inSSIDer is actively developed and has a much broader range of supported NICs, including recent ones. But inSSIDer will not have any noise data, just overlapping networks.

Answer (score 0):

I think kermit will tell you a range of stats about the wireless network itself that you might not normally see. netperf can be used to test the network performance.

Be aware the single strengh is only one measure, you care about the single/noise ratio, dropped packets, whether there are other SSID's transmitting on the same channel.